# Unable to change database owner to a user that is already mapped as user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, permissions

I ran into this problem.  Trying to change a database owner to `acct1`; however, I get the following error message when doing so:

> The proposed new database owner is already a user in the database

Now I know one solution is to drop the `acct1` user and then change the database owner, but I can't do that because all the tables in this database are owned by the `acct1` schema.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily change the schema ownership to `dbo`, then you should be able to drop the user, and add them back using `ALTER AUTHORIZATION`:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[schema_they_own] TO dbo;
DROP USER [user_name];
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[database_name] TO login_name;
```

Now, they will be the `dbo` user in the database (and will have automatic ownership of the schema).

You may need to change more than one schema; you can generate a script to do this using dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::'
  + QUOTENAME(s.name) + N' TO dbo;
'
FROM sys.schemas AS s
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dp
ON s.principal_id = dp.principal_id
WHERE dp.name = N'database user name';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

If you are happy with the command generated, you can copy and paste the output and run it, or you can uncomment the `EXEC` and run it again.

Comment: But I think in order for the application to work, the tables need to be under the schema owned by the the user and not the dbo user.  So would I be able to run "ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::dbo TO login_name;" after the database owner has been changed to login_name?

Comment: The application isn't going to care who has authorization on the schema. The tables will still belong to the same schema (you are [referencing the schema name explicitly in your app, right](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)?). You can't change the schema to be owned by `login_name` because `login_name` doesn't exist in the database. Since you mapped `login_name` to `dbo` (by making them the database owner), the user name is now `dbo`. Perhaps you should ask yourself why you want this user to be the database owner.

Comment: Once I run `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::acct1 TO dbo;`, shouldn't all the tables become dbo.table_name instead of the original acct1.table_name?

Comment: @Chinesinho NO. Did you try it? This isn't renaming `acct1` to `dbo`. It is merely changing its ownership. Ownership of a schema is not the same thing as the schema container of a table - it is just confusing in this case because `dbo` has multiple purposes.

Comment: I did and when I try to run "DROP USER [user_name];" after "ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::acct1 TO dbo;", I get the following: "The database principal owns a schema in the database, and cannot be dropped."

Comment: @Chineshinho then you didn't alter all of the schemas they currently own.

Comment: How do I undo the following t-sql "ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::acct1 TO dbo;"  Users are complaining that they can't get into the application now.

Comment: Well, what error message are they getting?

Comment: Nevermind, they're able ot get back in once I set the user to be db_owner.